# Swift Segmentation Fault with Non-Adoption of Extension

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

If I have a protocol, `MyProtocol` defined as:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func myFunction() -> String
}
```

and I have a default implementation declared in an extension so that conformers can "optionally" implement the function:

```
extension MyProtocol {
    func myFunction() -> String { return "" }
}
```

everything should work just dandy.

However, when a class conforms to that protocol and doesn't implement the functions, the compiler fails with `Segmentation fault 11`. Once the class implements the function, the error goes away and all is good with the world but it seems to defeat the purpose of defining default implementations in extensions.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Is it because the conforming class declares that it implements the methods so the compiler ignores what's written in the extension, can't find the methods and then crashes?

Comment: A crashing compiler is a bug and should be reported to Apple. However, I cannot reproduce your problem with Xcode 7.1.1. Adding `class MyClass : MyProtocol { }` to your definitions compiles (and works as expected).

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem. What version of XCode are you using? Are you using a version that supports this language feature of default implementations?

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005), Swift 2.2. It doesn't happen every time, only about half the time so it seems more likely than not a compiler bug, so i'll report it.

Answer (score -1):

I also had a similar problem with `protocol extensions` and `Segmentation fault 11`.
In my case the problem was, that in the `extension` I put the `mutating` keyword before the function, but in the `protocol` there was no `mutating`. And instead on an error this lead to that `Segmentation fault 11`.

Maybe that helps a bit.